# using window messages in qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

i want to handle **WM_DEVICECHANGE**  to detect insertion of usb devices. However i also want to write the gui in [qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).
**Question**
How do i access window messages when using [qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) on windows?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`QWidget::winEvent`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#winEvent).

Comment: This should not work because QWidget::winEvent wont handle system wide messages.

"To handle system wide messages, such as messages from a registered hot key, you need to install an event filter on the event dispatcher, which is returned from QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()."

Comment: That's "system-wide" messages (NULL HWND) as opposed to messages directed at a specific window. WM_DEVICECHANGE is not systemwide, but only to the window registed via `RegisterDeviceNotification`.

Comment: Ok if RegisterDeviceNotification is used to register a specific windows this could be true.